# How to add TObject to PVirtualNode.Data of TVirtualStringTree.Root node

Tags: delphi, lazarus, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

That is my question.

How I can put object to root node of tree? 
I know about addChild function, but it's for sub-nodes of root node. I need put data into root node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
TVirtualStringTree.AddChild(nil,TMyObject) ...
```

`nil` are equal to root node.